# NextJS tracking scroll position. window.ScrollY always equals 0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an app which has re-usable components which are fed in from ACF from WordPress and the components themselves are built with React.

On one of the pages [slug.js], I am trying to implement an event listener. Basically, on scroll, I want to log the scroll distance from the top of the page. However, everytime I log it, window.scrollY ALWAYS equals 0.

Also, if I use window.addEventListener instead of document.body.addEventListener, nothing will log. The function will not even run.

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong exactly?

I am putting this at the beginning of the function.

```
const Product = ({ page, componentData, seo }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scroll = (event) => {
      console.log(window.scrollY);
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("scroll", scroll);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: What about window.addEventListener(“scroll” ?

Comment: If I use window instead of document.body, it doesn't even log anything.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-kjxjqp?file=pages/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event should be added directly to the document.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 const options = { passive: true }; // options must match add/remove event
 const scroll = (event) => {
  const { pageYOffset, scrollY } = window;
  console.log('yOffset', pageYOffset, 'scrollY', scrollY)
 };
 document.addEventListener("scroll", scroll, options);
 // remove event on unmount to prevent a memory leak
 () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", scroll, options);
}, []);
```